# Intellij Idea keep deleting project files

Tags: java, intellij, gradle

I have a project, it is a Gradle project, and everytime I close Intellij it deletes the src files, they still exist in the directory just not in the idea project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thing that is deal with IntelliJ cache. Try to refresh Gradle configuration. Open [Gradle Tool Window](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/gradle-tool-window.html) and click refresh button [image]
.

I had the same issue with Maven and refreshing was helpful for me. Also may be useful [system cache clean up](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/cleaning-system-cache.html).